# Nuget Package multiple .csproj files

Tags: nuget

Say I have a few projects relating to the same module:

```
Project.ModuleA.Data.csproj
Project.ModuleA.UI.csproj
Project.ModuleA.Helpers.csproj
```

They don't depend on each other BUT they do have some shared dependencies

This works for individual projects

nuget pack Project.Data.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects

but Is it possible to pack all three into one package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported right now, probably you can manually author a .nuspec file that gathers all of the interesting lib files and content files.